# PHP site hangs randomly on firefox4

Tags: php, javascript, firefox4

I have a website that we coded that has worked flawlessly for over a year. Now since Firefox4 is out we have noticed an issue. Randomly the page just hangs. I have tried IE8/9, Chrome10+, Safari and Opera and have never noticed the issue.

Any ideas on a way to track down this issue? I am trying to avoid tossing a bunch of debug code in since this is a live sales site.

**

Checked in firebug and while its hanging there is no js loaded. The line that it appears to be choking randomly on is `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`

Comment: Impossible to diagnose with this little info. You will need to clarify at least *where* it hangs - loading the body, parsing the body, running JavaScript...?

Comment: Not sure how this could be PHP. PHP only outputs to the browser. It could be Javascript if you are using that on the site. Get the Firebug addon and use it to check the javascript.

Comment: Yeah I am being blonde, js didn't even track in my brain.

Comment: @cdburgess Yeah firebug doesn't really show me much. No js is loaded according to fb, but I will keep digging.

Comment: Can you provide a URL? we can do all kinds of testing if you can provide a URL.

Comment: "I am trying to avoid tossing a bunch of debug code in since this is a live sales site." - Why don't you replicate it on a test environment?

Comment: @scunliffe I 'could' give you a url but it would be useless, it appears only for users who have accounts, and accounts are auto generated on sale completion.

Comment: @MrStatic if you can post the rendered page code to a http://pastebin.com/ even that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, especially with the slim details, but it may.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged question with 'javascript' -- maybe you have `document.write` somewhere in JavaScript executing after document has been loaded?